# Does jQuery UI operate solely within the HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

At the risk of sounding inexperienced (which I am), I feel the need to ask the very simple question: **does jQuery UI operate solely within the HTML document?**

It relates to a problem I'm having with some javascript on my very first jQuery website. You see, I've just finished a course on Javascript, HTML/CSS, and jQuery each (all at [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com).) I'm trying to use [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to insert tabs into the website. However, when I link the HTML document to a separate javascript (.js) document, it doesn't work. The tabs appear, but the content of each tab is all lumped together on the first page (instead of being sorted into each separate tab.) And when I click on each tab, the body doesn't appear to change. I've searched both the web and this site for answers with no luck. All of the tutorials I've seen were outdated. The syntax offered inside of the "API Documentation" for "Tabs" seems unclear to me. Here's my code:

**HTML:** webdesign1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
        Your Company Name!
    </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="webdesign1.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webdesign1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=".tab1">Tab 01</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab2">Tab 02</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tab3">Tab 03</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab3">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:** webdesign1.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".tabs").tabs();
});
```

Comment: The problem you are facing is probably an error, like a syntax error, in the JavaScript that prevents jQuery tabs from constructing the tabs properly. Check out the error console to see what goes wrong. The answer to your original question is "yes" but it's beside the point in this case.

Comment: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525)

Answer (score -1):

Put your Jquery scripts before your other scripts and at the bottom of your body like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webdesign1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Fixed order of scripts.

Comment: Have you tried this out? While putting JS at the bottom is not automatically wrong, the order you suggest the files be included in is bound to cause a  crash. Also I don't see how putting the JS files into a different location would address the OPs problem

Comment: I can't include HTML tags in a jsfiddle or I would have tried it out. However, the order was certainly wrong as I meant to correct initially and could certainly lend itself to Jquery code not working correctly.

Comment: But why would JavaScript that doesn't work suddenly begin to work just because you move it from the document head to the bottom? It may be a performance improvement to do so, but it doesn't fix errors, does it?

Comment: I appreciate both of you even considering replying to my question. And also, seeing as how I'm still getting the hang of applying what I've learned to actual sites, even quick little comments like "rearranging the order of those tags you got there will improve performance" are doing me a HUGE favor. So thank you both!

(Although I'm not sure if I'll be using it in this case, if (like Pekka said) the order suggested may cause a crash.)

Comment: @RexReaver No, this is actually the correct order to list your scripts in and it should not make your page crash. I accidentally left them in the original order first (before my edit) and that is what Pekka stated first and originally downvoted me for. However, it very well could have been a correct answer because of how you were loading your scripts. He just responded/downvoted before I could correct my answer.

Comment: @acloudbuster Oh, I see! Well, even though your idea didn't resolve the issue in the original post, you should know I'll be using your tag order to increase the performance of all my web pages from now on. Thank you, acloudbuster!  Also, my issue just resolved by changing each class defined in the HTML document above to IDs with ID names that matched that found on the original jQuery UI Tab web page ( http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ ). If you click on 'View Source' on that page, you can see what the IDs are meant to be called. Thank you all for your help!